# Is it possible to target Specific Android phones using the /res/values folder

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm developing an app that targets only Android Phones, not tablets. The app should work in portrait mode only. I have all the dimensions (for views and fonts) in a dimens.xml file in the values folder.

I want to adjust the appearance for some commonly used phones, for example

- Galaxy S2: 240dpi, 480x800
- Nexus 4: 320 dpi, 768x1184
- Nexus 5: 480 dpi, 1080x1800

I want to specify some font size and view dimensions specifically for these targets. I've tried with a lot of different values folder names, for example:

values-sw240dp
values-sw480dp
values-sw320dp, and so on,

but the app uses always the same folder for the three devices (normally the 480dp folder).

It is  possible to specify dimensions in a resource file targeted for these devices?

Thank you in advance!

PS: excuse my bad English.

Comment: It seems you have an `hdpi`, an `xhdpi` and an `xxhdpi` device... so, use `value-hdpi`, `value-xhdpi` and `value-xxhdpi`.

Comment: Read it very carefully. It has all answers regarding UI Management for android : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: me too facing same problem did u find the solution..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Every single folder inside the `/res/` folder works exactly the same regarding those filters (xhdpi, sw600dp, en, land, etc).

The problem on your case is that you did not specify the correct folders. And the correct folders depends on what is the parameter you're using to specify the different dimensions.

- `sw___dp` is for "smallest width", meaning, the smallest width of the screen (in a 800x480 phone is the 480 side) is that amount of DPs.
- to specify DPIs you probably want to use `hdpi`, `xhdpi`, `xxhdpi`. Which will fit into those 3 devices you mention.
- If you really want to use `sw___dp`, you probably want to install [THIS APP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.qbus.sizemeup) on the devices and it shows you the sizing in `DP` for each screen (alternatively, if you don't have the devices, you'll have to do some math.

Comment: thanq that app was really very helpful for development to know the size of the device..

Answer (score 1):

[here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) is a comprehensive documentation of all the qualifiers you can use for resource folders.

It seems the best you can do is to use the dpi classes, and actually, I think that it's more correct cause you are optimizing you resources for every device in that class instead of only a specific few leaving the others to unknown results.

Answer (score 0):

Not for specific devices, but for device sizes, it is possible using value folders named like these (width-height):

> values-w480dp-h800dp